# Sort data based on column in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, odoo

Is there a way to sort the data before writing into excel using xlsxwriter? I am trying to create a sorted excel report based on a column in odoo.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the data as a pandas dataframe and sort it as indicated on the pandas documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html

As an example on the website, the exemplary pandas data frame `result` is sorted as follows (where `df` is the unsorted data frame):

```
import pandas as pd
result = df.sort(['A', 'B'], ascending=[1, 0])
```

Then you can use the pandas Excel Writer and convert the dataframe to an Excel Sheet. Further information is indicated on the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

The exemplary pandas data frame `result` is written into an Excel sheet using the following syntax:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: please consider to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer escpecially the following part: `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.` After that edit your answer please :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I did adjust my comment taking into consideration the information provided by you. Best regards